# React Hooks State is reset after use a fuction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, algolia

I stuck using React Hooks state. I am practicing with a weather app. I am requesting to Open Weather Map and a component called [algolia-places-react](https://github.com/kontrollanten/algolia-places-react). It connects to Alglia API to request name places.

I'm trying to make the request when the city name change. It looks it is working OK, But something is changed the value state to the initial state, before setting the new state. It happens on handleChange function. For example I added a new variable state and its function for checking that: *`count`* and *`setCount`*. When it enters to handleChange the console always prints: `1`, except the first time. It isn't incresing. The same case with *`{name: 'boston', countryCode:'us'}`* always it is printing *`{name: 'boston', ountryCode:'us'}`*, except the first time.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Segment, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import AlgoliaPlaces from "algolia-places-react";

export default function TempetureForm() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [city, setCity] = useState({name: 'boston', countryCode:'us'});
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = ({ suggestion }) => {
    console.dir(suggestion)
    setCity({name: suggestion.name, countryCode: suggestion.countryCode})
    setCount(count + 1) 
    console.dir(count) // Always prints 1
    console.dir(city)  // Always prints {name: 'boston', countryCode:'us'}
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.dir(city)
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city.name},${city.countryCode}&appid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setData(data));
  },[city]);

  return (
    <Segment basic>
      <Form>
        <Form.Field width={6}>
          <AlgoliaPlaces 
            placeholder='How weather is in ...'
            options={{
              appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
              apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
              language: 'en',
              type: 'city',
            }} 
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        {city.name + " " + city.countryCode}
          <p>{data && data.weather[0].description}</p>
      </Form>
    </Segment>
  );
}
```

Comment: setCity and setCount is asynchronous so, console.dir prints previous value because it doesn't wait for the values to be set.

Answer (score 0):

first, checking whether the value updated just after calling setCount is not the way to go since the value is not updated yet. someone suggested it's because setting the value is asynchronous. i didn't know that but it makes sense.

the `console.dir(city)` in your `useEffect` should show the updated value after `handleChange` was called as it's being called when `city` is updated.

Comment: That has sense, but what about the state is reseting everytime that handleChange function is executed. It always prints and renders 1 (in case of count variable), instead of increasing.

Comment: try using `setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1)` instead.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I don't understand yet, why in that method the value is being reseted to the initial value before the new value. Did you get it?

Comment: does it happen with `city` as well?